# netty 4 performance: multi channels or only one?

Tags: performance, netty

I use Netty 4.0.23 in my RPC framework, I found in client, when creating multi channels, performance is better than creating one channel. Why? Any method to improve performance in one channel?need I move encode/decode from Netty io worker thread to user thread?

Comment: It's highly dependent on your codec. If it is in some way blocking or slow, then obviously the send/receive will be slow. And if you have multiple channels, it means that the very same codec is used multiple times so almost linear acceleration, but only due to slow codec. Change your codec to other thread than worker thread could help of course, but still, the codec is the key... Could you explain a bit more what you use?

Comment: I have test making encode/decode simplest,but multi channel performance is better than one channel yet. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It is because when creating multiple channels, you'll utilize multiple CPU cores. When creating a single channel, you'll utilize only a single CPU core.

As the number of the channels increases, you will not see this performance improvement anymore because your CPU or your remote peer's CPU will be maxed out soon.