# Netty channels and multithreading

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to write a small java client using netty for transmission of log messages over a tcp connection. I'm fairly new to netty, so I was wondering about a few things

I will have multiple queue consumers reading messages and sending logs; is it OK to use one channel, or one channel per queue consumer? The handlers are stateless, and all data is sent to the same endpoint - from my understanding, one channel should be thread safe, multiple channels may offer better performance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28019260/3755871

Multiple channels allow use of more processors core, so more performance up until you have as much channels than your number of cores. And yes, a single channel is thread-safe.

Then again, depending on your traffic, you may not even notice a difference.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few factors to consider such as the number of queues being serviced, the total expected throughput of messages and the size of the messages. You might consider a *ChannelPool* for optimal performance.

Comment: Ah, never knew about the channel pool - I suppose the best thing to do is try with a 'shared' channel, and if the queues back up I can try out the pool

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went with combining both approaches - a FixedChannelPool set to the number of available processors (discovered using the NettyUtils helper class) which seems to be working well so far!